# Custom class in .fxml file doesn't get imported after obfuscation

Tags: javafx, proguard, fxml, fxmlloader

So I successfully imported a custom class in my .fxml class as follows

```
<?import com.company.project.controller.myCustonClass?>
```

Everything works fine and my program works as expected. After I added pro guard to my application, the program doesn't work. I get an

```
FXMLLoadException
```

The details of the exceptions are give below [ taken from log.out ]

```
myCustonClass is not a valid type.
file:/F:/xxxxx/xxx/xxx/project-name/target/jfx/app/project-name.jar!/fxml/MyScreen.fxml:21
```

I have found a workaround for this one. I just add an exception in the .conf file  like this

```
-keep class com.company.project.controller.myCustonClass
```

Is this the only way to handle the problem. The class name looks kind of weird in the debugger, while every other class has been 'obfuscated'

As suggested in [ProGuard breaks JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307262/proguard-breaks-javafx-application), i have added a .txt file with capital alphabets, yet my application doesn't work.

I used a debugger JD-GUI and i see all the obfuscated class names have capital alphabets. So it doesn't look like an issue with 'fxml unable to load class names with small letter'

**Update**:
I used another debugger 'jadx' and I see the import statement :

```
import com.company.project.b.A
```

but in the .fxml file I see the tag

```
<CustonClass ................../>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProGuard breaks JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307262/proguard-breaks-javafx-application)

Comment: I have already gone through the link and I have followed whatever the accepted solution suggested in the link, and it still doesn't seem to work. I will update the question with more details. Thank you